# Is graphite grease suitable for bicycle bearings?

Tags: maintenance, grease

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_lubricant#Graphite) doesn't explicitly list the applications of graphite grease. *Would it be suitable for bicycle bearings and threads?*

Furthermore, I went ahead and purchased a single package (the same price as the lithium grease). It says (translated):

> Water-resistant calcium anti-frictional grease. Contains 10% powdered graphite. Intended for lubricating sliding parts (like springs, chains, ropes), which are susceptible to quick wear, contamination etc. at temperatures from -20C to 65C."

Comment: As it says, it's intended for lubricating sliding parts.  Not ideal for ball bearings.

Comment: DanielRHicks, actually the [Wikipedia article on dry lubricants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_lubricant) lists **ball bearings among graphite grease applications**. But can that be trusted? What area of application of ball bearings? Is graphite grease inadequate in some respect (lubrication, water isolation, etc.). The question stands.

Comment: "Dry lubricants" are not a good choice for ball bearings, as they do not exclude water.  The #1 role of bicycle bearing grease is to keep water out.

Comment: @DanielRHicks another disadvantage, that was observed while using graphite grease, is that it exhibits the colour of contaminated grease. Litium, on the other hand, is nicely blond, turning darker as metal dust and mud are introduced.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel R Hicks's answer-as-a-comment:

> As it says, it's intended for lubricating sliding parts. Not ideal for ball bearings. –  Daniel R Hicks 2015-06-23 11:48:24Z
>
> "Dry lubricants" are not a good choice for ball bearings, as they do not exclude water. The #1 role of bicycle bearing grease is to keep water out. –  Daniel R Hicks 2015-06-25 12:05:18Z